# typescript - Why are comma separated private variables disallowed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Can anyone please tell me why the following private variable declarations are termed as invalid syntax by the compiler-:

```
class A {
    private a: number = 10, b: number = 10;
}
```

The error message is `';' expected`. Whether I put the semi-colon or not it has no change on what the resultant java script is.

You can verify this at the [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).

Comment: I know nothing about Typescript but [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) does not make any reference to being able to declare several members in the same statement. Is it possible that it's not supported rather than disallowed?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Why wouldn't you suppose something as basic as this ?

Comment: As I said, I know nothing about the language, it wasn't my intention to add noise. I might just remove the comment. If it actually works, it'll possibly be a bug in the online editor.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Even VSCode gives an error. Its not a problem with the online editor. If it is a problem, then it is a problem with the language implementation.

Comment: @ng.newbie  TypeScript seems to want to make Javascript programming more like C# (which is a good thing).  I don't think it was an oversight but a conscious choice on their part so that accessibility modifiers in class definitions would be explicit and clear.  It is one thing to initialize a bunch function variables using one "let" or "var" comma delimited but doing this for a properties and method definitions on a class would hurt readability in my opinion.

Comment: (Un)related: [Why doesn’t this feature exist?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanearp/2007/04/12/why-doesnt-this-feature-exist/). Happy weekend everybody!

Comment: @ng.newbie: You can read [this note on proposals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Writing-Good-Design-Proposals.md), then [write an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues).